# SimpleXMLElement, How to Avoid Entity Errors? (Entity 'Acirc' not defined in ...)

Tags: xml, dom, entity, character

How can I avoid as many entity conflicts as possible in an environment where the XML doc is containing blog-post type content?

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1104: parser error : Entity 'Acirc' not defined in ... (path)
```

The line causing this error:

```
$results = new SimpleXmlElement( $xml );
```

I also have control over the functions that produce the XML document. I've been attempting to fix the entity-parse errors using this function on each element introduced to the DOM:

```
function my_special_entity_function($text) {
    $text= html_entity_decode($text,ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-1"); #NOTE: UTF-8 does not work!
    //$text= preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me',"chr(\\1)",$text); #decimal notation
    //$text= preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei',"chr(0x\\1)",$text);  #hex notation

    return $text;
}
```

Lastly, I am using `DOMDocument()` to create the XML file. It generally works fine except for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

XML, unlike HTML, only knows four named entities: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;`and `&quot;`.  To teach it more, you need a DOCTYPE with entity declarations; XML Schema will not help you.

Comment: So what is generally the best way to do this? Using DOMDocument().

Comment: Actually, why are you using entities like `&Acirc;` at all? Can't you create the XML as `UTF-8`, and just use the un-encoded characters like Å?

Comment: This is due to user input that I didn't expect. Apparently their image data includes it...the xml is tripping over it. 
If there are any other solutions in even generically hopping over all unrecognized entities it would be great. I just need to stop it from crashing.

Comment: To expound on this a bit, the user has these characters coming out of their image meta (regarding a german photo) **"äÄöÖüÜß"**. I suspect this will be the first of many such incidents. Good thing this is a beta test :D

Comment: Why is this data embedded in the XML file? If it must, is it an element or an attribute?  Cn u\you use a CDATA section?